# Change File Encoding Info

Tags: encoding, sftp, utf-8

I'm having some trouble uploading text files using sftp. The trouble is, that the files on my (windows) client are utf-8 encoded, but after the upload they seem to be us-ascii encoded (at least *file -bi* says so).

The files have not been converted, I think only the meta data about the encoding is wrong. Is there any way to change that information? (Preferably multiple files/directories at once)

I've tried uploading using FileZilla as well as WinScp, with different configurations (force utf-8 enabled, automatic etc...), but had no luck avoiding the issue.

Comment: There is no metadata about encoding in a text file. This is why you should explicit it in most programming languages. What are you trying to do?. Which is inside those files?. How are you trying to open them?.

Comment: They're mostly .php code files. All I want to do is access them through the browser. (The Ubuntu machine serves as Apache web server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text files don't usually have any meta data. You just have to know what's inside yourself. Actually, on Ubuntu the default 'locale' (i.e. the default way to interpret text files) is also utf-8, so if it doesn't work for you then it's the specific program that doesn't support it, not the OS.

Note that us-ascii is a subset of utf-8, so the only way to tell the difference would be to scan the entire file for the multibyte characters, and you probably don't have any (unless you're writing in Chinese or Arabic or something).

Comment: You are quite right... I'm such an idiot, when testing a file that actually contains characters that differ from ASCII, the type is UTF-8. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, I don't think `file` scans the whole of large files, so it might sometime report ASCII even though there's a UTF-8 char somewhere near the end.